# Looking to create a responsive fading header effect using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is my very first post so please, if there is any additional information I can give or clarification on something I say, please don't hesitate to ask.

I am looking to create a header that fades from one image to the next according to what section the user is currently viewing.

What I have currently is the header images set to change according to what that the Y positioning is, as shown here:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
if (y > 0) {
    $('#img1').fadeIn({});
}
else {$('#img2').fadeOut('fast')};
if (y > 500) {
    $('#img2').fadeIn({});
}
else {$('#img2').fadeOut('fast')};

if (y > 1000) {
    $('#img3').fadeIn({});
}
else {$('#img3').fadeOut('fast')};

if (y > 1500) {
    $('#img4').fadeIn({});
}
else {$('#img4').fadeOut('fast')};
```

While this does work, it is not an effective solution when trying to make a site responsive. I have each of my sections IDed ("section-1" "section-2" and so on) and was hoping to create code that would change the header according to the section ID the user is currently viewing. I was told that a div array might help in this instance, but I'm still very new to Javascript so I'm not sure how to attempt this.

Any help that could be given with this project would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** Adding in the HTML and the CSS for just the header portion of this project, but if you need to see additional code, just let me know.

*HTML*

```
  <header class="pull-center" id="masthead">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <div id="img1"></div>
          <div id="img2"></div>
          <div id="img3"></div>
          <div id="img4"></div>
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <a class="brand brand-ctg" href="#section-1"><span></span></a>
              CTG
              <span></span>
          </a>
          <div class="nav-collapse">
              <ul class="nav">
                  <li><a href="#section-2">Demo Reel</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#section-3">Portfolio</a></li>
                  <li><a class="brand brand-ctg" href="#section-1"> <span></span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#section-4">Contact</a></li>
                  <li><a href="http://www.colortheblog.com" target="_blank">Blog</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

*CSS* (currently I have only the "img" div css, but if you need to see more, please let me know)

```
#img1 {
    display: block !important;
    background: url("http://www.colorthegrayscale.com/images/headers/headericon-blue.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 0 transparent !important;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed !important;
    right: 0;
}
#img2 {
    background: url("http://www.colorthegrayscale.com/images/headers/headericon-salmon.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 0 transparent !important;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed !important;
    right: 0;
}
#img3 {
    background: url("http://www.colorthegrayscale.com/images/headers/headericon-yellow.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 0 transparent !important;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed !important;
    right: 0;
}
#img4 {
    background: url("http://www.colorthegrayscale.com/images/headers/headericon-mint.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 0 transparent !important;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed !important;
    right: 0;
}
```

**EDIT 2**: New code for demonstration purposes

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
if ($("#section-1").scrollTop()) {
    $('#img1').fadeIn({});
}
else {$('#img2').fadeOut('fast')};
if ($("#section-2").scrollTop()) {
    $('#img2').fadeIn({});
}
else {$('#img2').fadeOut('fast')};

if ($("#section-3").scrollTop()) {
    $('#img3').fadeIn({});
}
else {$('#img3').fadeOut('fast')};

if ($("#section-4").scrollTop()) {
    $('#img4').fadeIn({});
}
else {$('#img4').fadeOut('fast')};
```

});

Comment: Can we see your HTML?

Comment: The CSS would be helpful too. Welcome to SO KarenD

Comment: Edited the original post to contain the HTML and the CSS. Hope this helps! And thank you for the welcome, crazymatt. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, your problem is that your `if{} else{}` commands don't match:

```
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
if (y > 0) {
    $('#img1').fadeIn({});
}
else {$('#img2').fadeOut('fast')};
```

"If we're at the top, fade in #1, otherwise *fade out* ***#2.***

Depending on the HTML ordering (thus the stacking of the images) Img1 may be on top in the z-order, so with it never fading out, it never reveals the other images.

You should reconsider your if-statements, so that each has a maximum *and* minimum value that are appropriate for any given header image.  Not to mention that if your content changes size, your scroll heights are now incorrect (you should calculate them based off an achor's scroll position).

Nechemya Kanelsky's boxed solution may also be a better plan (I am unfamiliar with both sites).

Comment: I added the HTML and the CSS to the original post in case you would like to look at it.
I actually do have the fading working as of right now; the Img1 is overlapped with the Img2 and then down the line, but the change is currently dictated by the Y positioning, not what section the user is currently looking at. Hope this helps!

Comment: I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bywvp5x/) of your current code.  It looks like it is functioning correctly except that on-load img4 is visible.  This is easily solved by using `$(document).ready()` to `.hide()` images 2,3, and 4 (or using CSS to `display:none`).

Comment: The code does work, but the problem is that I don't want it to change on the Y position (which is what the code currently does). I would like it to change according to what section the user is currently viewing (identified by div ids "section-1", "section-2", ext.

Comment: I'm sure how exactly to use the code you've provided, could you please elaborate? Thank you for your help so far :)

Comment: It returns a number.  "The vertical scroll position is the same as the number of pixels that are hidden from view above the scrollable area."  Use that value instead of your magic numbers.

Comment: I added the code and it doesn't seem to be working. However, as I am still a novice in Javascript, I could be entering the code in the wrong place. I added it into the original post as "Edit 2" to show what I currently have.

Comment: @KarenD Turns out I was using the wrong method, you actually want `.offset()`:  https://jsfiddle.net/ee2uztpc/

Comment: That did it!! Thank you Draco! You've been such a huge help!